# Monaco Editor How to work with suggestions

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, monaco-editor, autosuggest

I'm working on a React project where I use the Monaco Editor. Now I wanted to add my own language so I can make suggestions and auto-complete.

My MonacoEditor render looks like this:

```js
<MonacoEditor
  width="800"
  height="400"
  language="mygrammar" 
  value={monacoContent}
  onChange={handleMonacoChange}
/>
```

It is displayed and works fine. Now I registered mylanguage and added some syntax highligting + some suggestions.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    monaco.languages.register({ id: 'mygrammar' });
  
    let keywords = ['LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'BREAK'];
  
    monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('mygrammar', {
      keywords,
      tokenizer: {
        root: [
        [ /@?[a-zA-Z][\w$]*/, {
          cases: {
            '@keywords': 'keyword',
            '@default': 'variable',
          }
        }],
          [/".*?"/, 'string'],
          [/\/\//, 'comment'],
        ]
      }
    });
  
    monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('mygrammar', {
      provideCompletionItems: (model, position) => {
        const suggestions = [
          ...keywords.map(k => {
            return {
              label: k,
              kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Keyword,
              insertText: k,
            };
          })
        ];
        return { suggestions: suggestions}
      }
    })
  }, []);
```

The syntax highlighting works fine, but I don't get any suggestions. When I type "LE" into my Editor field I hoped for a suggest "LEFT". But nothing happens. Even when I press control + space I don't even get the suggestion window, I had in another project. What am I doing wrong?

I used this tutorial: https://ohdarling88.medium.com/4-steps-to-add-custom-language-support-to-monaco-editor-5075eafa156d

But already had to change monacoEditor too monaco, so I think it is kinda deprecated.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I can't tell why

```js
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('myLanguage', {
                provideCompletionItems: (model, position) => {
                    const suggestions = keywords.map(keyword => ({
                        label: keyword,
                        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Keyword,
                        insertText: keyword
                    }));

                    return { suggestions };
                }
            });
```

, but hey it works.